# How to provide the path of trust store file?

Tags: java

I have a java maven project where my truststore file(abc.pem) is inside the resources folder.

How to give the **path** for this?

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path of a file in `src/main/resources` with `getClass().getResource("/path/to/file")`.

For example, if resources contains a single file called "file.txt", the code `getClass().getResource("/file.txt")` will return the absolute path to the file as a URL object (note the leading slash).

Comment: getClass().getResource("/file.txt") will return URL object right ?